# How to enable multithreading for dsyev when wrapped with pybind11 in c++

Tags: c++, lapack, pybind11, blas, lapacke

I am trying to wrap a some of c++ code with pybind11. But, I am not able enable multi-threading for LAPACK/BLAS functions.

Currently, I just use ‘-fopenmp’ while compiling with gcc to enable parallelisation. With this I am able to parallelise other functions like matrix-matrix multiplication from Eigen but not the LAPACK/BLAS functions.

Comment: That would probably depend on the LAPACK/BLAS library you're using